# Can you check your progress before moving to next stage?

Tags: spore

I seem to be unable to find out myself, but is there a way to check your progress after achieving the milestone to reach the next stage? For example, if during cell phase I get enough to move to land, but I want to check if I am following the correct diet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to check your history before evolving is to hit the <kbd>t</kbd> button. This brings up the species his<kbd>t</kbd>ory. Once you are done looking, hit the <kbd>t</kbd> button again. This is the only way not to be locked in to evolving. However, if you like the current arrangement, you can go ahead and evolve.

Comment: Confirmed, this is excellent.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing preventing you from saving, evolving to the next phase, and, if you got a dissatisfaction result, reload your save game.

Comment: aka save scumming.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro Spore is not a roguelike (that would've been something though).

Comment: Well, sounds about the most logical thing to do. It just sad you have to take extra time with the loading and stuff.

Comment: You don't have to save scum as there is a way to check your species standing prior to evolution. See my answer for details.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to view your progression without forcing evolution. The only solution I can think of is view your progression before you reach your evolution goal, and modify your diet/behavior as such